# How to pass argument to function triggered by Button in Gtk#?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I'm trying to pass file in FileChooser in Gtk# and them using second button read from this file. I can't pass FileChooser to function, which is triggered when second button is clicked.

```
namespace SharpTest{
    internal static class SharpTest{
        public static void Main(string[] args){
            Application.Init();

            var window = new Window("Sharp Test");
            window.Resize(600, 400);
            window.DeleteEvent += Window_Delete;

            var fileButton = new FileChooserButton("Choose file", FileChooserAction.Open);

            var scanButton = new Button("Scan file");
            scanButton.SetSizeRequest(100, 50);
            scanButton.Clicked += ScanFile;

            var boxMain = new VBox();
            boxMain.PackStart(fileButton, false, false, 5);
            boxMain.PackStart(scanButton, false, false, 100);
            window.Add(boxMain);

            window.ShowAll();
            Application.Run();
        }

        private static void Window_Delete(object o, DeleteEventArgs args){
            Application.Quit ();
            args.RetVal = true;
        }

        private static void ScanFile(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs){
            //Read from file
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *FileName* property in **FileChooserButton** *scanButton* holds the name of the file chosen. The problem you face is that you cannot access the button from *ScanFile()*, since it is outside *Main()*, and *scanButton* is a local reference inside it.

Also, you are using an old-style fashion of creating event handlers. You can actually use lambdas for that purpose (the easiest option), and modify the parameters in the call to *ScanFile()* the way you like.

So, instead of:

```
scanButton.Clicked += ScanFile;
```

you can change it for:

```
scanButton.Clicked += (obj, evt) => ScanFile( fileButton.Filename );
```

which will do the trick, provided that you change *ScanFile()* to be:

```
private static void ScanFile(string fn)
{
   // ... do something with the file name in fn...
}
```

With that lambda, you are creating an anonymous function that accepts an object *obj* (the sender of the event), and an **EventArgs** *args* object (the arguments of the event). You are doing nothing with that info, so you dismiss it, since you're just interested in the value of the *FileName* property in *scanButton*.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. Also if you have some sites or articles to recommend me, I'll grateful.

Comment: You can learn about Gtk# here: http://zetcode.com/gui/gtksharp/ Also, I have a repository with a few demos here: http://github.com/baltasarq/GtkSharpDemo

Comment: Thanks again, you saved my project.

Comment: Ok, what if I want to change whole window. For example, when I click on button i want to remove everything from Window and display Label with some text instead.

Comment: You can have a hidden panel, and when the event arrives, hide the current panel and show the hidden one. If you still need help, you'll have to create a different question.